# Many-to-Many Relationships through 3-way Legacy Junction Table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

With a legacy database where the many-to-many relationships between projects, the people in the projects, and their roles in that project are represented through a three-way junction table like so:

[image: data relationship]

How would one represent this data in with Django models?

I'm trying to write a model where `project.manager` would return a list of `person` instances that are paired with the `manager` role for that `project_id`. So far, the closest I've gotten is using `models.ManyToManyField` through two of different fields in `Rolepersonproject`, but that only gives me the roles and people associated with that project, not what roles those people played. How would I do this? Is this a job for custom managers, the ManyToManyField, model methods, or custom SQL?

`manage.py inspectdb` gave me model classes like these to work with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(db_column='project_id', primary_key=True)

class Role(models.Model):
    role_id = models.AutoField(db_column='role_id', primary_key=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.AutoField(db_column='person_id', primary_key=True)

class Rolepersonproject(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='project_id')
    role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='role_id')
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='person_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the models that inspectdb gave you, after you add `related_name='rolepersonprojects'` to each of the Foreign Keys in `Rolepersonproject`, you could add a property onto the `Project` model something like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def manager(self):
        return self.rolepersonprojects.filter(role_id_id={{ id of manager Role }}).values_list('person_id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay over the weekend. I'll try this out right now. Thanks!

Comment: This worked great. Although, I left out `values_list` to have access to all the fields in the other tables.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped!